# A train starts from X towards Y, which is at a distance of 55 km, at a speed of 40 km per hour.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A train starts from $X$ towards $Y$, which is at a distance of $55$ km, at a speed of $40$ km per hour. After running a certain distance, it increases its speed to $50$ km per hour and reaches $Y$ in $1$ hour and $15$ minutes after leaving $X$. After what time did the train change its speed?

My attempt: $$x/40+(55-x)/50=75$$

Comment: $$x/40+(55-x)/50=75$$

Comment: Sequences and series?

Comment: @sonystarmap, We are losing out ! Correct No ? Sequences and series tag looks awesome

Comment: @jyothika, please see what you are posting !! That tag makes absolutely no sense !! Don't just ask whatever comes to your mind !!

Comment: @jyothika, since you are considering speed in km/hr, the total time should be in hour, 1hr 15 mins is 1hr+(1/4) hr=(5/4) hr

Comment: @jyothika If the first comment was supposed to show your attempt at the solution, it would have been better to include that in the post rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As the train is moving at a constant speed until it changes to a different constant speed, its journey is governed by the equation,

$$s = v_1t_1 + v_2t_2$$
where $s$ is distance traveled, $v_1$ and $t_1$ are speed and time of the first half, and $v_2$ and $t_2$ are the same for the second half.

We know that the total time taken was 1 hour and 15 minutes, or 1.25 hours. We know that up until time $t_1$ the train is moving at 40 km/h, and afterwards it is moving at 50km/h. Therefore we have
$s = 55$,
$v_1 = 40$,
$v_2 = 50$,
$t_2 = 1.25 - t_1$.

Hence putting these values into the above equation, we can solve for $t_1$, the time at which the train changes speed.
$$40t_1 + 50(1.25-t_1) = 55$$
$$\implies 62.5 - 10t_1 = 55$$
$$\implies t_1 = 0.75 \text{ hours}$$
$$\implies t_1 = 45 \text{ minutes}$$

Comment: Thanks for giving the correct answer, since I had an error in my calculation!

Answer (score 0):

The distance between $X$ and $Y$ is $55$km. You start at $40$kph and keep this velocity for a time $T$ after which you accelerate to $50$kph.

Let $T$ be measured in minutes. $40kph=\frac23\frac{min}{km}$ and $50kph=\frac56\frac{min}{km}$.

Then
\begin{align}
&\frac23 \frac{km}{min} \cdot T +\frac56\frac{km}{min}(75min-T) = 55km
\\ 
\Leftrightarrow
&\frac23T+\frac56(75min-T)=55min
\\ 
\Leftrightarrow
&\frac23T+\frac56 75min-\frac56 T=55min
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&\frac23T-\frac56 T = 55min -\frac5675min = 55min - 62.5min = -7.5min
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&-\frac16T = -7.5min
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&T = 45min
\end{align}

Thus, you drive with $40$kph for the first $45$ minutes and then you accelerate to $50$kph.

Comment: Oh god I'm embarrased. Thanks to @Dom Kennedy I noticed that my answer was wrong. (I was too lazy to calculate $\frac56 75$ and since I had no calculator I used python and for python $75*5/6=62$. I should've used $75*5/6.=62.5$)
Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

By alligation it can be solved in the following way.
If traveling was done at uniform speed , then avg speed would have been 
55 /(5/4) km/hr= 44 km/hr.
Now, by alligation it can be determined the ratio of  time traveled in 40 km/h and 50 km/h is 3:2.
Hence time traveled in 40km/h speed =(3/5)*5/4 hr =3/4 hr =45 mins